# UDP parallel ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: udp, python-multithreading

I need to receive messages from different UDP ports.
My code works, but I cannot figure out why messages wait for each other! What I mean is that if I send a message not in the dict order, the message is not passed through the function.
Function waits for each cycle to change the port.

```
import concurrent.futures, socket

ports = {}
ports['BRAIN'] = 10015
ports['REAPER'] = 10025
ports['CSOUND'] = 10000

def receive_from(port):

    host = 'localhost'
    buffer_size = 4096
    udp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    udp.bind((host, port))
    
    while True:
        score = udp.recv(buffer_size).decode()
        return score

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for key, port in ports.items():
            print(key + ' udp connection is started!')
            future = executor.submit(receive_from, port)
            print(future.result())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried to use `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `ProcessPoolExecutor`, but maybe it's not the right solution. Should I use the `threading` or `multiprocessing` library?

IMPORTANT: I used `concurrent.futures` because I needed to get the return from my function in the `main()`

Answer (score 0):

The function waits to change the port because of the call to future.result(), which waits until the future has completed.  Instead of that, collect all the futures into a list and print their values in a second loop, like the script that follows.

This script starts three threads.  They all run in parallel, and the returned values are printed out in order as the futures complete.

I replaced your UDP stuff with a simple time delay so I could actually run the program.

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

ports = {}
ports['BRAIN'] = 10015
ports['REAPER'] = 10025
ports['CSOUND'] = 10000

def receive_from(port):
    time.sleep(1.0)
    return port

def main():
    futures = []
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for key, port in ports.items():
            print(key + ' started')
            futures.append(executor.submit(receive_from, port))
    for future in futures:
        print(future.result())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```